# C program to print a triangle of stars

Tags: beginner, c, iteration

This C code is to print a triangle of stars.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<i*2+1;j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

which works well though, I'd like to know if there is a better way to do the job, as it's said 2 layers of loop is inefficient, compared to vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the size of the program, I have only a few things to suggest

- Since you aren't returning anything from `main()`, use `int main(void)`.
- Use don't have to perform any arithmetic in the inner nested-loop, you only need to do `j <= i`
- `3` in the outer-loop is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#:%7E:text=The%20term%20magic%20number%20or,1%20manuals%20of%20the%201960s.) or, an **unnamed numeric constant**. I suggest you assign it to `const int rows`, to make it clear

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int rows = 3;

    for(int i = 0;i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            printf("*")

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I believe this will be the best, and easiest way to perform this task!

Answer (score 2):

I use a string to avoid the inner loop. The problem here is the `printf()` inside. A 3000-row triangle redirected to `/dev/null` takes 50ms, but now only 4ms.

I reformatted the output. And I left dots as fillers to see what is going on.

```
$ ./a.out 
...*...
..***..
.*****.
*******
```

It starts with one `*` in the so-called middle, and every row-iteration only sets two more bytes to `*` before it prints.

The complicated part is preparing the string i.e. array of chars. You can use `calloc()` to clear the right side, but it still takes a step to put blanks on the left side.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int trihi = 4;
char PIX = '*';

int main(void){

    int width = trihi * 2 - 1;
    char s[width + 1];
    memset(s, '.', width);
    s[width] = '\0';

    int mid = trihi - 1;
    s[mid] = PIX;
    printf("%s\n", s);

    for (int i = 1; i < trihi; i++) {

        s[mid - i] =
        s[mid + i] = PIX;
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

This should add up. `s[mid + i]` runs up to `2*mid` = `2*(trihi-1)`.
The '\0' sits at `width = 2*trihi - 1` which is one higher, and is the highest legal index for `s`.

It is very easy to make a small mistake and not have the `\0` at the correct place.

It also works with a triangle height of 1:

```
$ ./a.out 
*
```

And by setting `... = --PIX;` in the loop:

```
$ ./a.out 
.....*.....
....)*)....
...()*)(...
..'()*)('..
.&'()*)('&.
%&'()*)('&%
```

**The So-Called Middle**

This is how a triangle of height 4 is laid out. Size is 8. The middle is s[3]; there are 3 spaces to the left.

```
01234567  --- "offset", "index"
...*...0
|  |   |
|  |   +-- s[width]  (width = 2*trihi - 1)     
|  +------ s[mid]    (mid   = trihi - 1)   
+--------- s[0]
```

You start with trihi=4, but what you need is mostly 3 and 7...the geometrical base width is also 7.

---

**Just any Triangle**

If this is enough (with original height = 3):

```
$ ./a.out 
*
**
***
```

then the code gets much simpler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int trihi = 3;
char PIX = '*';

int main(void){

    char *s = calloc(trihi+1, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < trihi; i++) {
        s[i] = PIX;
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
}
```

I kicked everything out except the basic idea: re-using a prepared string/array. Here the calloc-zeroes are only after the PIXes. No need for a filler like space or dots via memset() anymore. But it is also not the same user experience...and the triangle is half the size.

Overiq.com has a double-loop version of a *C Program to print Half Pyramid pattern using **. It takes much longer than the above (*tri2.c* below).

```
$ gcc -O2 over.c           
$ time ./a.out |wc -l
3001

real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.014s
$ gcc -O2 tri2.c 
$ time ./a.out |wc -l
3000

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.011s
```

Comment: Your answer is almost a good one. Currently your observation about the performance of the program is implied, if you actually mention it in the answer it would be better.

Comment: With redir to a tmpfs file it is 54ms vs. 11ms. I don't know what you mean with "imply" or "mention". I tested and mentioned it.

Comment: It is the OP who mentioned efficiency, and I think he is right to ask. His way would work well with curses, I guess, where you "refresh" when done modifying.